# SSH tunel with aws SSM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-iam

Hopefully this helps someone else since I spent hours trying to figure out how to connect from my local machine (macosx) over SSH to an ec2 instance in the private subnet which acts as a tunnel to other resources like redis, rds.

Why exactly do I need to access my private subnet resources? I want to be able to test the RDS database, redis, and private API Gateway for an application that I am building.
Why did I go with the SSM approach over OpenVPN, Bastion host in the public subnet, or something else? 1) I don't have till the end of time to finish building my MVP, and 2) I read from various sources that placing a bastion host into a public subnet can lead to some vulnerabilities from a security perspective.

The SSM approach seems to work nice for my sandbox environment, which is currently 1 VPC with 1 public and 1 private subnet in only 1 availability zone. I can download temporary AWS CLI credentials, issue aws ssm console commands, and setup tunneling for the various services which reside behind the private subnet.

I'll list the steps that I took, but it does seem a bit cumbersome to run these steps each time I want to setup a tunnel to the services in the private subnet, where as some vpn services seem to integrate fairly easily without the added hassle. Please let me know if you have a better solution, or a way to improve my approach.

**The setup:** first I'll go over the various steps that I took in this approach.

1. I used the VPC Launch Wizard to launch a VPC with 1 public and 1 private subnet into (us-east-1c)
2. I launched 1 redis instance into the private subnet
3. I launched 1 EC2 instance using the Amazon Linux 2 AMI into the private subnet. I did not enable public access on the instance.
4. I created an IAM role which I assigned to the EC2 instance. The role contains a policy called: AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore, although the guide that I was reading explains to make your own IAM policy (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-getting-started-instance-profile.html), it's a bit fuzzy to me as I am not that experienced with IAM and I wasn't entirely sure how to set it up, although I do believe I created the policy correctly and attached it to the role which I attached to the EC2 instance. Even following the above guide which provides kms encryption and logging, I did not see any logging being submitted to cloudwatch or s3. Unsure if these components are super critical, but if anyone has input please share.
5. I created an IAM user with programatic access only. Although I am using the root account for this "sandbox" account, I don't think it is possible to get API keys for the root user, so that is why I created a secondary account.
   I could not get AWS ssm console commands to work from my local machine without attaching policies AmazonSSMFullAccess and EC2InstanceConnect (can someone confirm if these are actually required?) to the IAM user that I created.
6. I installed the awscli package using pip3 for Python on my local machine
7. I installed the SSM plugin for macosx (again my local machine) (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager-working-with-install-plugin.html#install-plugin-macos)
8. I configured aws credentials for the IAM user that I had created in step 4 (just run aws configure in the console) and you will be prompted to enter various values.
9. I was able to start a session to the EC2 instance in the private subnet by running:

   aws ssm start-session --target i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

   Output:
   sh-4.2$
10. This https://prismatic.io/blog/connect-to-aws-resources-with-ssh/ guide helped me complete the remaining steps that included adding a public key to the ec2 instance using the following command:

    aws ec2-instance-connect \
    send-ssh-public-key 
    --availability-zone us-east-1c \
    --instance-id i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 
    --instance-os-user ec2-user 
    --ssh-public-key file://$HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

I'm not entirely sure why this step is needed, but if someone has any clarification please add.

11. Added this to my `$HOME/.ssh/config`

    host i-*
    ProxyCommand sh -c "aws ssm start-session --target %h --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=%p'"
12. I could then setup my first tunnel to redis. This command creates an SSH tunnel from localhost:5000 on my laptop to the redis instance.

    ssh ec2-user@i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -NL 5000:some_rds_aws_url.cache.amazon.com:6379 -i test.pem -v

I'm also not sure why the .pem file is still required, but if anyone has information as to whether that is not actually required, or another way to obscure this. Without the pem file, I face: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).

Please share any feedback, positive or negative, about this approach.

Answer (score 1):

You're facing the issue because when you run SSH using this proxy-helper `host i-* ProxyCommand sh -c "aws ssm start-session --target %h --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=%p'"`, all you're doing is creating a oport tunnel between you and the AWS EC2 instance on port 22 (by default).

This is why you're seeing an issue with connecting to the instance without the key, as you need to SSH to the instance prior to using that to jump to the redis server.

Your connection will traverse the internet in a similar fashion to this:

```
ssh command -> aws ssm start-session -> internet -> ec2 server -> redis
```

If you don't want to use your SSH keys, I'd suggest looking at VPN options to connect to the internal resources instead:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/awsmarketplace/setting-up-openvpn-access-server-in-amazon-vpc/